# My python code output in VSCode is different from the output I recieve when running my code in my mac terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

```
sum = 0
codeid = input("Please enter your ID code: ")

if len(str(codeid)) == 10:
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [0]) * 10
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [1]) * 9
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [2]) * 8
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [3]) * 7
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [4]) * 6
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [5]) * 5
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [6]) * 4
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [7]) * 3
    sum = sum + int(str(codeid) [8]) * 2
    remainder = sum % 11
    if remainder >= 2 and (11 - remainder == int(str(codeid) [9])):
        print ("valid ID")
    elif remainder < 2 and (remainder == int(str(codeid) [9])):
        print ("valid ID")
    else : 
        print ("Invalid ID")          
else: 
print ("Invalid ID")
```

So this is a simple code I've created for detecting either a specific type of ID is valid or not. for example the number "0462519449" is valid due to the algorithm and the output returns "valid" when I run the code in VSCode; however, when I save the program and run it from terminal, I get the output "invalid ID" which is not true since it must be valid.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Also, if you output in every error situation the same message _Invalid ID_, you are not seeing at which place the checking fails. This makes it unnecessarily difficult to debug. Either use different error messages in each case, or differentiate the cases via the exit code. Your program now returns exit code 0 even in the error case, which is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: what is wrong with good old debugging, we did not have SO 20 years back and we where able to find and fix problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the terminal you're using Python 2.

In Python 3, `input` returns a string (so all your `str(codeid)` calls are unnecessary).

In Python 2, `input` evaluates whatever text it's given, so if you type in 0462519449, it will return an int. Specifically, it will return the int `462519449`, since the leading zero has no effect. Then your check `len(str(codeid)) == 10` is false, which is why you get to "Invalid ID".

If you're running Python 2, you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.